# how to make html page by link name

Tags: asp.net, html

I am building a page for produce name "product.aspx"

I have display some products in this page with hyperlink.

Now I want, when I click my product (such as pen) then it automatically makes an html page name pen.html with some information.

When I click clock then it automatically makes an html page name clock.html with some information.

How can I do this?

I am using asp.net C# 3.5.

Comment: What kind of information should the created page have? Where is this information coming from?

Comment: Are you sure this is good? If you have thousands goods you will find thousands pages!! Why can't you have one page to manage all goods reading their info from a database?

Comment: the information comes form database

Comment: And how do you know what information to get from the database in order to create the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Literal to crete your html page
in frontend ypu can add Literal

so in backend code you can create a html page by adding text to the literal

eg.

```
var productdata = datasource;

ltrProduct.text ="<head><title>"+productdata.title+"</title></head><body></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than actually creating a physical file for these products, its best to have a Web Form called something like "Product.aspx" which you pass a querystring to like:

> /Product.aspx?product=Pen

This can then be [URL Rewritten](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) to something like:

> /Product/Pen.aspx

You can then use this query string to return data like:

```
Dim cmd as new sqlcommand("SELECT Name, Price FROM Products WHERE FileName=@FileName", Conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", Request.QueryString("product"))
```